# Behavior of smooth functions near boundary

Tags: real-analysis

I am very confused about the following, which stumped me as I was trying to understand the Rankine-Hugoniot jump condition:

Say $u: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is $C^1$, where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is open. How is the statement "$u$ is $C^1$ on $\overline{\Omega}$" understood?

Further, if $\partial_t u + \partial_x f(u) = 0$ on $\Omega$, shouldn't $\partial_t u + \partial_x f(u)$ be $C^0$ and thus $\partial_t u + \partial_x f(u) = 0$ on $\partial\Omega$ as well?

Comment: Can you also provide the source?

Answer (score 1):

"$u$ is $C^1$ on $\overline{\Omega}$" means that $u$ is continuously differentiable in $\Omega$ and continuous on $\overline{\Omega}$. In particular, the value of $u$ at a point on the boundary of $\Omega$ is equal to the limit of $u$ along a sequence converging to that point.

Assuming that $u$ is defined on an open set containing $\overline{\Omega}$ for the expression $\partial_tu+\partial_xf(u)$ to even make sense, there's no reason why the derivatives have to be continuous on the boundary. Note that the continuous extension of $u$ from $\Omega$ to $\overline{\Omega}$ is unique, and this continuous extension need not be regular with respect to the derivatives.

Comment: Can you provide the reference (to the definition)?

Comment: The interior of $\overline{\Omega}$ need not be equal to $\Omega$.

Comment: @PhoemueX great point--I tried to be too cute and it backfired.

Comment: @JohnMa I don't have a reference on hand--this is the notion that is usually implied when I see statements like this. Without more information on where the source of OP's statement is, I can't really say anything more than that this is what I think is right, based on my experience.

Comment: @JoeyZou My experience is a little different. I would interpret it as $u$ being the restriction of a $C^1$ function on $\mathbb R^n$, and I would call your space $C(\bar\Omega)\cap C^1(\Omega)$. If you replace 1 by 2 you will actually see this notation showing up in the statement of the maximum principle.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, one defines a function $u: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ to be $C^1$ at a point $x \in \partial\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ if $u$ extends to a $C^1$ function on $V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, where $V$ is an open neighborhood $x$.